# Set an item as full row in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am willing to do a layout with this kind of design.

[image]

I am using a GridView with three columns. But what I don't know is how to set in my custom adapter that one of the items will fill a whole row.

**Layout**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
private class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList hashmap = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String[]> hashmap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.hashmap = hashmap;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_item, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);


        String[] temp = (String[]) hashmap.get(position);
        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]));
        textView.setText(temp[1]);

        return gridView;
    }
```

Comment: What you want is a `GridLayout`, instead of a `GridView`

Comment: Isn't there a more dynamic solution for this situation? Because with the gridLayout, all the items inside have to be set in the layout, and it isn't dynamic as using a GridView.

Comment: You can set the LayoutParams programmatically, if so you wish. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Using a Recycler View could help to fulfill of still making all of the data inserted to this view, dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reduce the layout width from match_parent to wrap_content?